# Unable to access property of type java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet

Tags: java, jsf-2

I am iterating unmodifiableSet of type EquityStatisticsSet which have instance variable statisticsCurrency. while  iterating  i am getting following error Property 'statisticsCurrency' not found on type java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet.

**where i am going wrong? plz help me.**

*following are xhtml and java file.*

.xhtml file:

```
<p:dataTable id="equityStatisticsTable"
             value="#{commonStockController.equityStatistics}"
             var="equityStatistics">

  <p:column headerText="#{res.business_equity_statistics_statisticsCurrency_Label}">
    <gs:textInput
     inputName="business_equity_statistics_statisticsCurrency"
     inputValue="#{equityStatistics.statisticsCurrency}" />
   </p:column>
```

java code:

```
 public Set<GSEquityStatistics> getEquityStatistics(){
      return new HashSet<GSEquityStatistics>(commonStock.getAllStatistics());
     }

 public Set<GSEquityStatistics> getAllStatistics() {
      return Collections.unmodifiableSet(equityStatisticsSet);
    }
```

Exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: /content/business/security/commonStock.xhtml @166,64 
inputValue="#{equityStatistics.statisticsCurrency}": Property 'statisticsCurrency' not found on type java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet
 javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
 org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:147)
 org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

Comment: Does your <gs:textInput is an input component ?

Comment: @RongNK yes <gs:textInput is a <p:textInput>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Until the upcoming JSF 2.2](http://jdevelopment.nl/jsf-22/#479), `UIData` components don't support `Set` interface. They only support e.g. `DataModel`, `List`, `Object[]`, `ResultSet`, etc. As per JSF 2.2, the `Collection` will be added, which not only covers `List`, but also `Set`.

Your current best bet is to convert the `Set` to an array via [`Set#toArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#toArray%28%29) with help of the new EL 2.2 ability to invoke arbitrary methods:

```html
<p:dataTable ... value="#{commonStockController.equityStatistics.toArray()}">
```

**However**, this is fairly expensive as the `toArray()` is basically invoked on every single iteration. Under the covers, the `toArray()` iterates over the entire `Set` and creates an array. There's no "backing array". This ends up in O(n^2) complexity instead of O(1) as in array or `ArrayList`. If you really can't convert it to an array or `List` in the model beforehand (not in a getter!), then you'd better use `<c:set>` to evaluate it once and store it in the request scope.

```html
<c:set var="equityStatistics" value="#{commonStockController.equityStatistics.toArray()}" scope="request" />
<p:dataTable ... value="#{equityStatistics}">
```